# Jenkins: Is there a way to perform post cleanup in based on a parameter chosen by a user

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have been trying to have a parameter set such as
parameters { choice(name: 'CLEANUP', choices: ['ALWAYS', 'ON FAIL', 'NEVER'], description: '') }

is there a way to perform the cleanup in post stage with deletedir()?

I have attempted some things such as a when expression in the post which is not allowed. I have also tried this:

`post { always { script { if(params.CLEANUP == "ALWAYS" || (params.CLEANUP == "ON FAIL" && currentBuild.result != "FAILURE")) { cleanup { deletedir() } } } } }`

Answer (score 0):

[Library vars](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) will be much cleaner descision:

**Pipeline**

```
@Library('myAwesomeLib')
#declare agent on pipeline level or use node('label') in post steps

pipeline{
  agent{label 'my-agent}
  parameters { --- your params ---}
  stages{
    stage{
      steps{
        ---do your staff---
      }
    }
  }
  post{ 
    always{
       myCustomCleanup(params.choice_name)
    }
  }  
}
```

**Library**

```
#vars/myCustomCleanup.groovy

def call(string myChoice){
   switch(myChoice){
      case('Always'):
         #sh "rm -rf ${env.WORKSPACE}" - not good
         cleanWs() # good 
      case('OnFail'):
         if(currentBuild.result == 'FAILURE'){
            cleanWs()
         }
    .... any other logic for cleanup....
   }
}
```

But. This is not good strategy for gitOps - you may save all important staff with *publish steps* or with *archiveArtifact* step and forget about old workspaces. Also if you not overiding workspace with *customWorkspace* option workspace will be reused in next builds.